# How can i add SAP B1 SystemForm to my new Module?

Tags: c#, sapb1

[image: My SAP B1 View]

I have created a new module that named "Bordro" and under the module i created a user form named "Puantaj Kartları". Now I wanna create a SystemForm(Employee Master Data) under the my Bordro module.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply create a menu item like your Puantaj Kartlari item and then add an event handler for the Menu_Click event of this new menu item and finally, in this event handler, call:

```
SBO_Application.ActivateMenuItem("MenuItemID")
```

Where "MenuItemID" is the Menu ID of the System Form you want to open (Employee Master Data is "3590", I believe).

Comment: What you're looking for is all documented in the SDK samples, I suggest you look through those. 

Stackoverflow doesn't like links as "answers", but take a look at the threads below from SCN:

Adding a new menu item: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3427356

Menu Events: http://scn.sap.com/people/lisa.mulchinock/blog/2009/11/26/ui-api-for-dummies--part-1-menus

Comment: Thank you so much @Overhed , I did it. Now I want to add a tab to my system form, can you help me for this?